# Building SurfaceFlinger from source in Android NDK and using tests directory contents

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, surfaceflinger

I am new to Android NDK programming.
My question is how to build the SurfaceFlinger library (.so) in Android NDK?
I have downloaded the required sufaceflinger source files from github and tried compiling them  using ndk-build command, and it asks for some header files.

Can anyone help me with, how to build the SurfaceFlinger shared library and including the required header files.

And also what is the use of the files from tests directory present along with source file and how to use it?

My target device is running Android 4.0.4 and my system is running on Windows 7 (32-bit).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SurfaceFlinger is not an NDK-buildable component.  You need to download the [full Android source tree](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) and build that.  Linux or Mac OS X is required.

In addition to the various headers and libraries you also need the target-specific hardware configuration defines.  If you look in the [SurfaceFlinger makefile](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/services/surfaceflinger/Android.mk) you can see it checking for `omap` and pulling in different `BoardConfig` values.  In other words, you need to build SurfaceFlinger for a specific device; it's not a generic device-independent library.

Comment: hi sir @fadden, if surfaceflinger is not ndk-buildable component then is there any way around to build **LibSurfaceFlinger.so**. Basically i am trying to build the libSurfaceFlinger.so file with little modifications so that i can see the GUI of remote android device like in VNC applications. Is there any other way to build the SurfaceFlinger library without downloading the whole AOSP. I am targeting this app for the certain specific device running on _Android 4.0.4_. How to compile (*_test.cpp, Android.mk)files present in the tests folder (for eg. libs/gui/tests/Surface_test.cpp).

Comment: You don't need the entire tree, but it's hard to say which parts you need -- things depend on other things.  The easiest way is to just grab the whole tree and build it.  It's unfortunate you can't target 4.3/4.4, as the "screenrecord" command added there demonstrates a much easier approach using virtual displays.

Comment: hi @fadden sir, my app is targeting Android 4.0.4(ICS) and not 4.3/4.4 if i gather all dependencies for surfaceflinger (header files), then will i be able to build **libsurfaceflinger.so** using _ndk-build_ or do i need to use some other tool? Basically i want libgui from remote device to interact with my device's libsurfaceflinger so that i can get display of apps running on server with which i can interact as if that app is installed on my device. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Possible, yes.  Easy, no.  The AOSP tree comes with its own build environment; full instructions can be found on source.android.com.

Comment: Hi @fadden sir, And what about the contents(*_test.cpp, Android.mk) in tests directory. What is their use and how to use them?

Comment: Those don't appear to be used anymore.  I tried building a few and they failed compilation.  I would ignore them.  The tests in frameworks/native/libs/gui/tests are probably more relevant.

Comment: Hi @fadden sir, what is the procedure to compile them?